# Excel VBA: Shift:=xlToLeft twice possible?

Tags: excel, vba, shift

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVhzK.png)I'm new to vba and struggling with the following problems.

I have a formula in the column (let´s say) "E:E"* written (not in the VBA Code), now I insert a new column just right next to it (with the VBA Code). The problem is, my formula won´t extend automatically.

Therefore when I change the place/position for the new added column, it will be between at least two already existing columns and the the formula will extend automatically...

```
Sub spalteeinfuegen1()
    Set Zelle_kostenstelle = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("1:1").Find(kostenstelle) 'Suche der Kostenstelle in der Tabelle1
    If Not Zelle_kostenstelle Is Nothing Then
       Zelle_kostenstelle.EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToLeft 'Einfügen der Tabelle auf der linken Seite und Abbruch falls er den Eintrag nicht findet
       Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, Zelle_kostenstelle.Column - 1) = UserForm4.TextBox1.Text 'Text aus der UserForm übertragen
    End If
End Sub
```

But how can I use Shift:=xlToLeft twice?

*the column "E:E" is just an example. In the VBA code I call it "kostenstelle" as it changes with each new insert it´s Position.

```
Sub spalteeinfuegen1()
Set Zelle_kostenstelle = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("1:1").Find(kostenstelle)
Zelle_kostenstelle.EntireColumn.Select
With Selection
        If Selection.Column > 2 Then
        Debug.Print ",e"
        .Columns(.Columns(Selection).Column - 2).Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
        Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, Zelle_kostenstelle.Column - 2) = UserForm4.TextBox1.Text
        End If
End With
End Sub
```

Somehow I´m confused, how to address the variable column "zelle_kostenstelle" properly...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim Zelle_kostenstelle As Range
    Dim kostenstelle As String
    kostenstelle = "FindMe"
    With Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        Set Zelle_kostenstelle = .Range("1:1").Find(kostenstelle)
        If Not Zelle_kostenstelle Is Nothing Then '< Test if anything was found
            If Zelle_kostenstelle.Column > 2 Then '<Make sure you can go back to columns to do an insert
                .Columns(Zelle_kostenstelle.Column - 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight '<perform the insert 2 columns to the left
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes and No. Yes, you answerd my question, the code works like that. But it inserts a new column two positions to the left and left one column free. Which makes sense. 
And No, I hoped it will insert the new column between two existing columns

Comment: It moves the rmentioned column two to the right. Isn't that what you were after?

Comment: It shoud jump two positions to the left and insert there the new column. So it will be between two existing columns. Now it just inserts the column two positions to the left and leaves a free column.

Comment: Have a look at the edit where it goes back two columns and inserts a column. Is that closer?

Comment: Somehow I´m confused, how to address the variable column "zelle_kostenstelle" properly...